# how to properly use ILRepack.exe in bash?

Tags: bash

Here is what I try to do in bash (want to create a dll called Program2, which merge Program.dll and nunit.framework.dll)

```
./ILRepack.exe /out:Program2.dll Program.dll nunit.framework.dll
```

And here is the error I get (and if I'm not wrong, I have a binary file)

```
ILRepack.exe: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

**Or maybe my arguments are just wrong?**

Comment: Operating system? Looks like you probably took a Windows binary to Linux or something and of course that won't work.

Comment: @4ae1e1 I know it is confusing but .NET assemblies can be run on lunux with mone....even when build on windows (and the other way around)

Comment: Okay, but the error message clearly says otherwise. Exec format is unknown to the OS.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Linux, you may be able to register Wine or Mono as the interpreter for such foreign binaries.  You'll need to have the `binfmt_misc` kernel module; the easy way to configure it is to install a package such as `wine-binfmt`.  On Debian, `mono-runtime-common` recommends `binfmt_misc`, so I would guess that it knows how to configure the module.